# Как исправить ошибку вида "go: no Go source files" во время сборки библиотеки

Tags: c, golang, dll

Имеется консольное приложение. Я попытался сделать из него библиотеку путем добавления импорта библиотеки C и пометок экспорта необходимых функций. До добавления - программа работала корректно, после - не собирается и не запускается. Единственная ошибка - "go: no Go source files"

После комментирования импорта C - все запускается.

Для проверки нашел рандомный текст для компиляции бииблиотеки. пример привожу
Текст:

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export GetIntFromDLL
func GetIntFromDLL() int32 {
    return 42
}

//export PrintHello
func PrintHello(name string) {
    fmt.Printf("From DLL: Hello, %s!\n", name)
}

//export PrintBye
func PrintBye() {
    fmt.Println("From DLL: Bye!")
}

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

Ошибка

```
go: no Go source files
```

Опять комментирую "C"

```
package main

// import "C"
import "fmt"

//export GetIntFromDLL
func GetIntFromDLL() int32 {
    return 42
}

//export PrintHello
func PrintHello(name string) {
    fmt.Printf("From DLL: Hello, %s!\n", name)
}

//export PrintBye
func PrintBye() {
    fmt.Println("From DLL: Bye!")
}

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

Команда сборки с использованием C. Файл с package main называется test.go. Пакетных нарушений при разделении по директориям - нет

```
go build  -buildmode=c-shared -o test.dll test.go
```

Проверку работоспособности пакета производил стандартным запуском. Логика - должно исполняться без ошибок

```
go run test.go
```

вывод go env. Вроде все пути корректны

```
PS F:\Tests2> go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\arr\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\arr\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\arr\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\arr\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.20.5
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=F:\Tests2\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\arr\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1201881241=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Все исполняется после комментирования импорта C, но не с этим пакетом. Команда и сборки и запуска выдает приведенную ошибку. С чем может быть связана ошибка?

Comment: Ранее уже собирал подобные пакеты, правда на Linux, все работало прекрасно. А тут ни в какую...

Comment: ¿тут - это где?

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос команду, которой вы пытались собрать `dll`

Comment: Добавил команду

Comment: Попытался собрать то же самое на виртуальной машине. Установлен только go и mingw_toolchain. Сбока приведенной командой и запуск проходят без проблем.

Comment: Проблема окружения, ваш код и команда успешно отработали. пути прописаны все? ```go env```

Comment: Добавил вывод go env. Пути все корректны получаются.